# MySQL delete a lot of data id by mybatis

Tags: mysql, mybatis

Hello，now I hava a question how to delete data id by mybatis.
Now,I have a SQL like this

```
  <if test="id!=null and id!=''">
     and  a.xxx=#{id}
  </if>
```

When I want to delete many data id,Usually I will send id to SQL.But when there  have many data id, I don't want to send  id at a time,this has a great impact on mysql.
 So I want to ask  If there has a data structure similar to Map or list, you can parse data in the database.
  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use IN and foreach in mybatis to send ids by type of list!